# How do i scrape words on a page in PHP to change a button type?

Tags: php

I'm using simple html dom to try and scrape words on a page and change the button if certain text appears.

If the words "out of stock" appear on a page, i want to reflect a different button than if those words don't appear.

My Code:

```
<?php
include 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';
$xeon5420 = file_get_html('www.wholesaleinternet.net/cart/?id=199');

?>

<?php foreach($xeon5420->find("out of stock") as $element);
if ($element == "out of stock) { echo <button 
class="btn btn-danger">Out ofStock</button> };
if ($element != "out of stock") 
{ echo <button class="btn btn-success">Order Now</button>};
?>
```

I'm getting all sort of errors

EDIT:

This is what i have now but still receiving errors :

```
<?php foreach($xeon5420->find("out of stock") as $element);
                        if ($element == "out of stock") { echo '<button class="btn btn-danger">Out of Stock</button>' };
                        if ($element != "out of stock") { echo '<button class="btn btn-success">Order Now</button>'};
                                ?>
```

Comment: You have parser errors galore. You need quotes around the strings after your `echo` commands.

Comment: _“I'm getting all sort of errors”_, _“This is what i have now but still receiving errors”_ – and you’re still doing an excellent job at letting no-one know what those errors actually are … clever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need simple html dom to check if a string appears in another string:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.wholesaleinternet.net/cart/?id=199');
echo (preg_match('/out of stock/i', $str)) ? '<button class="btn btn-danger">Out of Stock</button>' : '<button class="btn btn-success">Order Now</button>' ;
```